# with regex, why am i unable to get multiple lines to match in linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

i would like to get everything that is inside the `CreateCommand` below:

so, i've tried `CreateCommand(.|\n)*],` on the regex101 site:

```
            "CreateCommand": [
                "docker",
                "run",
                "-p",
                "3000:3000",
                "-v",
                "/home/blah:/usr/src/app",
                "-w",
                "/usr/src/app",
                "--name",
                "dev",
                "node:18-bullseye-slim",
                "npm",
                "run",
                "dev"
            ],
"Umask": "0022"
```

and it works great.

Then, i try `docker inspect dev | grep 'CreateCommand(.|\n)*],'`  and i get nothing.

I also tried:

```
docker inspect dev > insp.txt
cat insp.txt | grep 'CreateCommand(.|\n)*],'
```

so, it seems like i'm missing some kind of nuance here... because this gives me at least something:

`cat insp.txt | grep 'CreateCommand.*'` -->             `"CreateCommand": [`

edit:

i have tried a few different variations, including taking off some from the right side:

`cat insp.txt | grep -E 'CreateCommand((.|\n)*).*(?="Umask)'`

Comment: If this is JSON, I suggest to use `jq` for this.

Comment: @Cyrus will have to check that out, now i know not to use grep on json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` operates line by line; no regex will work.

Convert the output to a single line using `tr` to delete newlines, *then* use `grep`:

```
docker inspect dev | tr -d '\n' | grep 'CreateCommand.*]'
```

Comment: ok i did not realize it is line by line.

here are some ways i was able to do it:

`cat insp.txt | tr -d '\n\r\t ' | grep -oP '(CreateCommand").*(?="Umask)'`
or
`podman inspect dev | python -c 'import json, sys; print(" ".join(json.loads(sys.stdin.read())[0]["Config"]["CreateCommand"]).encode("utf-8") );'`